# python pandas combine text from multiple rows to one row

Tags: python, pandas

How can i get text belonging to the same key into one single row (and in the process deduping the key)?

For example, I retrieve only the dataframe rows where key = 'abc'. I get three cases where feedback has been provided. In order to do a wordcloud I need to get all the words into one list.

```
df1 =  df['feedback'][df['key'] == 'abc']
print df1
```

output

```
1             [10years+, experience, in, solicitors, pi]
345    [keen, to, help, where, they, can, , good, ser...
440       [professional, , knowlegeable, , competititve]
```

I need this to go into one row only and belonging to the key 'abc'

Comment: Does `df.groupby('key')['feedback'].apply(list)` work?

Comment: it does, thank you! just need to find a way now to get one list of comma separated words rather than multiple lists: (['competitive', 'pricing'], ['excellent', 'service'], ['very', 'quick'])

Comment: @raoulbia If you can, you should post an answer to the question, so it's not left open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

courtesy of EdChum:
Does df.groupby('key')['feedback'].apply(list) work?

yes